# How to get UserId or name from private instant Teams message

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to get the userID or userName of the user that just send me a Teams private message in PowerAutomate. The block "[When a new chat message is added](https://learn.microsoft.com/connectors/teams/#when-a-new-chat-message-is-added)" only gives me messageID and message link. The final goal is to create a log for all the message I would receive in Excel spreasheet or other database. The log would include date of the message and user who sent it.

If PowerAutomate is not the right tool to do this, please suggest another tool if needed.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not directly get it from the response. Try in this way -

1. Add next action of Teams "Get message details" and pass MessageID (received in the first response) and other channel details.
2. Add next action of Office365 "Search for users (V2)" and pass From User Display Name received in the above step.
3. Now you can get email id of the person from the 2nd step mention above.

Try something like this and this shall help you furthure.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Getting-User-name-from-Teams-message/m-p/1395368/highlight/true#M157228

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Your solution works for group or channel messages! I'm sorry Teams is in french for me so my terms were not exact... I am trying to get userId from a private chat message in Teams. From any user to me. Do you think this can be acheived in PowerAutomate?

Comment: I do not know what to put in the "Message Type" field of the "Get message details block". The options are "Group chat", "Channel" or "Enter custom value". No option for private or chat message... Do you have any idea?

Comment: I finally found the solution! I will post all the info tomorow!

Comment: I added "Get message details" Filling Message field with "Message ID" and Group chat feild with "Message conversation ID". Then added "Get user profileV2" filling User UPN field with "From User user ID"